# debconf not finding templates

Tags: debian, dpkg, debconf

I've been trying to generate a deb file for a personal project of mine.  The project uses sbt and sbt-native-packager to generate a deb file which I will install on my server.

I added a `templates`, `config`, and `postinst` script to my control archive (and confirmed that they are unpacked) but they debconf doesn't seem to detect the new templates.  `sudo debconf-show t-budget` comes up blank and every `db_input` returns `10 "t-budget/<template>" doesn't exist`.

Is there something I need to do to add these templates to the database besides have the files in my control archive?

Side note: I mentioned sbt-native-packager because it might be relevant that I'm not directly using the deb creation tools, but it looks like what I have should work and if this is a limitation of the tool, I'd like to know what the problem is so I could fix it.

These are the config files I'm trying to use:

```
$ ls -lht /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  27K Sep  4 21:54 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20K Sep  4 21:54 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.1K Sep  4 20:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.conffiles
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  815 Sep  4 20:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.9K Sep  4 20:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  100 Sep  4 20:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.postrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.9K Sep  4 20:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.preinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.9K Sep  4 20:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.prerm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K Sep  4 20:51 /var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.templates
```

`/var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.templates`:

```
Template: t-budget/database/ip
Type: string
Default: localhost
Description: What is the host of your PostgreSQL server?
 T-Budget needs a postgresql server to store it's data.
 You can host one locally or have it connect over the network.
 Enter the host's domain name or IP address.
 Note: If the database is not the localhost, the install script will not be able to configure it automatically.

Template: t-budget/database/name
Type: string
Default: budget
Description: What is the name of your database?
 A single postgres server can host several isolated databases.
 It is recommended that T-Budget run on it's own database to maximize security and data integrity.

Template: t-budget/database/username
Type: string
Default: t-budget
Description: What is the PostgreSQL username?
 T-Budget should use an isolated username with limited permissions to the rest of the system.
 To create a new user, enter a username which is not yet in use.

Template: t-budget/database/password
Type: password
Description: What is the PostgreSQL password?
 If creating a new user, it will be created with this password.
 If using an existing user, this password will need to match the current password of that user.

Template: t-budget/hostnames
Type: string
Description: What is the hostname of your server?
 What is the domain name of the server users will use to access T-Budget?
 Used for security protocols.
 You can input multiple hostnames seperated by a space.
 You can also prefix your hostname with a '.' to include all subdomains in addition to the hostname.
```

`/var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.config`:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# Source debconf library.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
db_version 2.0

echo "configuring..." 1>&2
db_clear
echo "CLEAR: $RET" 1>&2
db_purge
echo "PRUGE: $RET" 1>&2

db_input high     t-budget/database/ip       || true
echo "INPUT high t-budget/database/ip: $RET" 1>&2
db_input high     t-budget/database/name     || true
echo "INPUT high t-budget/database/name: $RET" 1>&2
db_input high     t-budget/database/username || true
echo "INPUT high t-budget/database/username: $RET" 1>&2
db_input critical t-budget/database/password || true
echo "INPUT critical t-budget/database/password: $RET" 1>&2
db_go
echo "GO: $RET" 1>&2

db_input critical t-budget/hostnames || true
echo "INPUT critical t-budget/hostnames: $RET" 1>&2
db_go
echo "GO: $RET" 1>&2

# TODO: validate input
```

`/var/lib/dpkg/info/t-budget.postinst`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Source debconf library.
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

# generate config files...
```

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at a working example from the offical repositories and piece-by-piece making it match mine, I found the problem:

```
db_purge
```

This line will remove all templates from the database.  I added it because I was copying another example so I'm not sure how that one worked, but removing this line fixed the problem.